# JPA @OneToMany Mapping Problems

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

In @OneToMany bi-directional Mapping, when i save the parent entity "User", child entity "Address" also save in table but, the id of "User" entity not store in "Address" entity related table

Comment: can you provide code for User/Address class and code to save?

Answer (score 0):

in a bidirectional mapping u have to do something like this

```
 @Entity
 public  class User implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
     @OneToOne(mappedBy="user")  //it reference the relation in Adress class
     private Adress adress;        }




 @Entity
 public  class Adress implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;

     @OneToOne
     private User user ;

}
```